# How are token values used in web sites?

Tags: html, asp.net, web

I'm wondering the hidden value in a website.

The website is built by ASP.NET.

When I had read its source code, I found a strange value.

It's not the first time to ran into this kind of code.

Some says that these values are used as a token to protect the website.

Can you give me more information?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking at is the [ViewState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475806/asp-net-how-viewstate-works). The token you refer to is a token against Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) attacks, like in [ASP.NET MVC's `AntiForgeryToken`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402770/what-is-the-use-of-anti-forgery-token-salt).